# Not able to remove 10.0.0.0/8 from route table aws vpc

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpc, routetable

I do not have classic link enable for my vpc may be  we had earlier  but there is an entry(10.0.0.0/8) in my vpc route table and there is no option to remove it .how can i remove it .

Comment: Route tables are associated with a subnet not a VPC. What is your VPC CIDR? 10.0.0.0/8 is way too large. Can you post a screenshot of your subnet route table?

Answer (score 0):

There is a **default entry in every Route Table** that is mapped to the CIDR of the whole VPC. It is routed to **local**, which means that all subnets in the VPC can communicate with each other. It is not possible to remove this entry.

[image: VPC Route Table]

If you do not wish some subnets to communicate with each other (which is common in a [DMZ scenario](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMZ_(computing)), you can use [Network ACLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_ACLs.html) to deny traffic within certain CIDR ranges (eg particular subnets).

Answer (score 0):

The issue will be due to classic link enabled on VPC, try disabling the same which should avoid this issue.

Comment: what is ** the same which** ?